# Get the Last Modified date for all BigQuery tables in a BigQuery Project

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have several databases within a BigQuery project which are populated by various jobs engines and applications. I would like to maintain a dashboard of all of the Last Modified dates for every table within our project to monitor job failures.

[image]

Are there any command line or SQL commands which could provide this list of Last Modified dates?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For a SQL command you could try this one:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)
FROM `dataset.__TABLES__` where table_id = 'table_id'
```

I recommend you though to see if you can log these errors at the application level. By doing so you can also understand why something didn't work as expected.

If you are already using GCP you can make use of [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) (it works on AWS as well), we started using it in our projects and I recommend giving it a try (we tested for python applications though, not sure how the tool performs on other clients but it might be quite similar).

Comment: We have log level job management covered, but have hundreds of tables updating and require one more concise view on what jobs are out of date at any given time.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do this for all datasets instead of a single dataset?

Comment: Hi Andrewwowens , can you please tell how you have addressed this issue, we are also having hundred of tables where i want visibility.

Comment: You can just remove the WHERE clause for all tables in a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I've just queried stacked `GA4` data using the following code:

```
FROM analytics_#########.__TABLES__
where table_id LIKE 'events_2%'
```

I have kept the 2 on the events to ensure my intraday tables do not pull through also.