# Programmatically check the last time a table has been accessed via a query?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a programmatic way to check the timestamp of when a table or view was accessed by a BigQuery query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain last modified via a meta query as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288261/get-the-last-modified-date-for-all-bigquery-tables-in-a-bigquery-project).

For last accessed, you need to enable Audit Logs.
Then you can query:

> SELECT timestamp FROM
>   `AuditLogsDataSet.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_YYYYMMDD`

See instructions how to [Analyzing Audit Logs Using BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs)