# Merging two queries in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-schema

I need to get table_schemna, table_name, creation_time and last modified time columns

using this query i am not getting table_name.

```
SELECT * FROM `region`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

using this query i am not getting Last modified time.

```
SELECT * FROM `region`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Is this possible to merge the above queries to get the required four columns or is there any other way to get the last_modified time ,creation time, table from multiple datasets

Comment: It sounds like you want to know when the TABLEs were last modified, correct? If so, you don't want to get your last_modified_time from the SCHEMATA table as that is going to give you the time the SCHEMA was last modified. Instead, I recommend trying this answer that will give you every column you need. The downside is that it needs to be run for each dataset but you could write a procedure to iterate through all datasets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290543/3907405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the below approach to get the table_id, creation time and last_modified time from datasets.

```
select table_id, TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
dataset_id
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple join query with your requirements.

**Query:**

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name,a.creation_time,last_modified_time FROM <projectID>.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES a
INNER JOIN region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA on schema_name = table_schema ;
```

Just apply the project ID and and proper region where your BQ dataset is situated. (Also apply proper role to access the tables schema)

Sample Output:
[image]